# undefined method `model_name' for Module:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `form_for` that is not meant to initialize an object, but rather just pass form data for the processing of a web payment.

I was advised to do `form_for ActiveModel`as a means to do this.

It was working fine for a while but suddenly I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Module:Class
```

which is being called on this line:

```
  <%= form_for ActiveModel do |f| %>
```

in my `application/pay.html.erb` file.

Here is the full file:

```
<%= form_for ActiveModel do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, params[:first_name] %><br />

  <%= f.label :last_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, params[:last_name] %><br />


  <%= f.label :card_number %>:
  <%=f.text_field :card_number, params[:card_number] %><br />


  <%= f.label :expiration_date %>:
  <%= f.text_field :expiration_date, params[:expiration_date] %><br />


  <%= f.label :cvv2_cvc2 %>:
  <%= f.text_field :cvv2_cvc2, params[:cvv2_cvc2] %><br />

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood.

ActiveModel is a module that you can include in your model classes.

When calling `form_for` you should reference an instance of a class that includes `ActiveModel`, e.g.

```
form_for(@article) do |f|
```

`model_name` is used by Rails to determine the name of the model, so the submit button will say "Update article" or "Create article".

Comment: okay but can i do a `form_for` for a controller method? this was working before by the way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704389/rails-4-form-form-controllermethodname-not-working frandroid's recommendation actually worked but now it doesn't.

Comment: I don't want to create an object, Niels, seulement, pass some form data to the server :)

Comment: You have to be more specific than "pass some form data to the server" - this describes every possible form operation.

Comment: I would like to send data via Post to a controller method called processs_payment, that has all the POST parameters from the form available to it.

Comment: Okay, then use `form_for(:payment)`, this should yield you a form object that nests all the attributes under a payment object, so you can do `params[:payment][:amount]` in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking to pass data to the controller, then you should use a `form_tag` helper.

A `form_for` automatically associates the form data with the attributes of the model object that the "form is for". For example

```
<%= form_for @payment do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :credit_card_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :credit_card_number %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

automatically maps the field :credit_card_number to @payment.credit_card_number when the submit button is clicked. Really, the submit button POSTs the form data to the create action and it is saved to the database. But if you don't want to save this data, and only need it temporarily to pass on somewhere else, use a form tag.

The form tag passes the form data to the `params` hash, like this:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: payment_processor, action: pay} ,method: HTTP_VERB) %>
    <%= label_tag :credit_card_number %>
    <%= text_field_tag :credit_card_number %>

    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Upon submit, this form will call the action of the controller that you indicated after the form_tag, and will pass the data in the form to the controller via the `params` hash as `params[:credit_card_number]`.

In summary, the `form_for` is intended specifically for saving form data as an instance of a model (i.e. putting the info in a database) while the `form_tag` can be used to pass any data to a controller via the `params` hash.

You can read some more about all this [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) in the rails guides. Hope this helps!